# A shell script to read a text file and then run a java program

Tags: java, shell

I have a java program that stops often due to errors which is logged in a .log file. What can be a simple shell script to detect a particular text line say

```
stream closed
```

and then run the following command

```
java -jar xyz.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a bash script to do something like that (may contain typos):

```
#!/bin/bash
tail -f logfile.txt | grep "stream closed" |
while read line
do
   java -jar xyz.jar
done
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if grep 'stream closed' filename.log >/dev/null
then java -jar xyz.jar
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

```
T1="`cat youfile.log  | grep 'stream closed'`"
if [ "$T1" = "stream closed" ]; then
   java -jar xyz.jar
fi
```